# Auto generating test data while maintaining table relationships/constraints

Tags: java, sql, oracle, testing, oracle11g

Given the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR
   (
    author_id number,
        author_fname    varchar(20),
        author_lname    varchar(20),
        author_telno    varchar(20),
        author_address  varchar(200)
)
/

 CREATE TABLE AUTHOR_BOOKS
   (
        author_id_book  number,
        author_id   number,
        boook_name  varchar(10),
        book_publisher varchar(20),
        published_date  DATE,
        published_country_code  varchar(3)
)
/
```

In the above two table structure, author_book.author_id is a foreign key to author.author_id meaning that an author can publish more than one book. 
How can i generate test data for both tables. I want to generate the test data on both tables e.g. 1000 rows in AUTHOR and 2500 rows in AUTHOR_BOOK.

The area that i am struggling with is what would be the easiest way to link the the primary key in the AUTHOR table with while auto generating the content for AUTHOR_BOOKS?

What are the possible approaches that can be used to auto generate test data for table that have a one to many relationship? I would be particularly be interested in solutions in Java, PL/SQL or simply just pure SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you would use ORACLE sequences to populate your ID columns.

Then in your seeding script, you would generate something like this:

```
insert into author values (author_seq.nextval, other columns);
insert into author_books values (book_seq.nextval, author_seq.currval, other columns1);
insert into author_books values (book_seq.nextval, author_seq.currval, other columns2);
...
insert into author values (author_seq.nextval, other columns);
insert into author_books values (book_seq.nextval, author_seq.currval, other columns3);
insert into author_books values (book_seq.nextval, author_seq.currval, other columns4);
```

Comment: Do  you mean manually creating the insert statement? I was thinking more of a solution similar to the use of DBMS_RANDOM but i dont understand how to enforce the referential integrity when dynamically generating the data

Comment: you can use dbms_random for the "other columns" to have diferent business values. ids are just keys to connect records so it doen't metter what values they should have. In real database you would use sequence any way, so why not to use them to generate sample data?